# git pull *after* git rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

I have a feature branch, and a master branch.

Master branch has evolved and I mean to have those updates to diverging as little as possible from master branch.

So I `git pull` in both branches, `git checkout feature/branch` and finally `git rebase master`.

Now here I either expect everything to work smoothly *or* conflicts showing up that I need to resolve before continuing rebase until all master commits are re-applied successfully on feature branch.

Now what really happened in my case is something I do not understand:

```
$>git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: myFirstCommitDoneOnTheBranch
Applying: myOtherCommitDoneOnTheBranch
$>git status
On branch feature/branch
Your branch and 'origin/feature/feature' have diverged,
and have 27 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$>git pull
*load of conflicts*
```

Now, as much as I can understand he load of conflicts after the pull; I do not understand the need for a pull. Logically, it should rollback to master when it got branched, save the commits made on the branch, forward to latest commit on master and then apply the saved commits.

I do not understand to what the `Applying` message refers to: what is applying the commits on which version?

Comment: do you have a backup of the branches on the remote?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

**tl;dr** You should update both `master` and `feature` with `git pull` and `git pull --rebase` **before** rebasing `feature` on top of `master`. **There is no need to do a** `git pull` **after** you have rebased your `feature` branch on top of `master`.

With your current workflow, the reason why `git status` is telling you this:

> Your branch and 'origin/feature' have diverged,
> and have 27 and 2 different commits each, respectively.

is because your rebased `feature` branch now has **25** new commits that aren't reachable from `origin/feature` (since they came from the rebase on `master`) plus **2** commits that *are* reachable from `origin/feature` but have different commit IDs. Those commits contain the same changes (i.e. they're *patch equivalent*) but they have different SHA-1 hashes because they are based off of a different commit in `origin/feature` than the one you rebased them on in your local repository.

Here's an example. Let's assume that this is your history *before* doing `git pull` on `master`:

```
A - B - C (master)
         \
          D - E (feature)
```

After `git pull`, `master` got commit `F`:

```
A - B - C - F (master, origin/master)
         \
          D - E (feature)
```

At that point, you rebase `feature` on top of `master`, which *applies* `D` and `E`:

```
A - B - C - F (master, origin/master)
             \
              D' - E' (feature)
```

In the meantime, the remote branch `origin/feature` is still based off of commit `C`:

```
A - B - C - F (master, origin/master)
         \   \
          \   D' - E' (feature)
           \
             D - E (origin/feature)
```

If you do a `git status` on `feature`, Git will tell you that your `feature` branch has diverged from `origin/feature` with **3** (`F`, `D'`, `E'`) and **2** (`D`, `E`) commits, respectively.

> Note that `D'` and `E'` contain the same changes as `D` and `E` but have different commit IDs because they have been rebased on top of `F`.

The solution is to do `git pull` on both `master` and `feature` *before* rebasing `feature` on `master`. However, since you may have commits on `feature` that you haven't yet pushed to `origin`, you would want to do:

```
git checkout feature && git pull --rebase
```

to avoid creating a *merge commit* between `origin/feature` and your local `feature`.

### Update on the consequences of rebasing:

In light of [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42861353/git-pull-after-git-rebase/42862404?noredirect=1#comment72898413_42862404), I expanded on the diverging branches. The reason why `git status` reports that `feature` and `origin/feature` *diverge* after the rebase is due to the fact that rebasing brings in new commits to `feature`, plus it *rewrites* the commits that were previously pushed to `origin/feature`.

Consider the situation *after* the pull but *before* the rebase:

```
A - B - C - F (master)
         \
          D - E (feature, origin/feature)
```

At this point, `feature` and `origin/feature` point to the same commit `E`—in other words, they're in "*sync*". After rebasing `feature` on top of `master`, history will look like this:

```
A - B - C - F (master)
         \   \
          \   D' - E' (feature)
           \
             D - E (origin/feature)
```

As you can see, `feature` and `origin/feature` have *diverged*, their common ancestor being commit `C`. This is because `feature` now contains the new commit `F` from `master` plus `D'` and `E'` (read as "*D prime*" and "*E prime*") which are commits `D` and `E` applied on top of `F`. Even though they contain the same changes, Git considers them to be different because they have different commit IDs. Meanwhile, `origin/feature` still references `D` and `E`.

At this point, you've *rewritten history*: you've modified existing commits by virtue of rebasing them, effectively creating "new" ones.

Now, if you were to run `git pull` on `feature` this is what would happen:

```
A - B - C - F (master)
         \   \
          \   D' - E'- M (feature)
           \         /
             D - E - (origin/feature)
```

Since `git pull` does `git fetch` + `git merge`, this would result in the creation of the merge commit `M`, whose parents are `E'` and `E`.

If, instead, you ran `git pull --rebase` (that is, `git fetch` + `git rebase`) then Git would:

1. Move `feature` to commit `C` (the common ancestor of `feature` and `origin/feature`)
2. Apply `D` and `E` from `origin/feature`
3. Apply `F`, `D'` and `E'`

However, noticing that `D'` and `E'` contain the same changes as `D` and `E`, Git would just discard them, resulting in a history looking like this:

```
A - B - C - F (master)
         \   
          D - E - F' (feature)
              ^
             (origin/feature)
```

Notice how commit `F`, previously reachable from `feature`, got applied on top of `origin/feature` resulting in `F'`. At this point, `git status` would tell you this:

> Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature' by 1 commit.

That commit being, of course, `F'`.

Comment: Thank you for this. But what I do not get is that I *did* do a git pull --rebase on both branches before rebasing and I end up with this. Just to make things clear: I am not rebasing on top of master but on develop though it should not change anything (and yes the command I use is git rebase develop not git rebase master). Still how come I still end up with this "diverged branches" thing?

Comment: @tisek I expanded on my previous answer. I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: This is *very* interesting. I am just not completely sure of what *should* be done: should I push (actually, will git let me do this ?) after my rebase? since from your explanation, the state of the feature branch locally is that it now has all updates from master + the feature specific ones? or run a git pull --rebase in order for git to (not) reapply the changes (except for the pure-master-ones (the F that becomes F' on the branch)) just to make git happy ?

Comment: If you want to publish the rebased `feature` branch, the only way would be to _force push it_ with `git push -f`. However, be aware that you would be publishing _rewritten history_ (in our example `D'` and `E' are effectively "new") so if someone else has created commits on top of the old ones (`D` and `E`) they would end up in the same situation after a `git pull`. So, if you can safely communicate to _everyone_ who might have fetched `origin/feature` that you're about to push rewritten commits, you'd be fine. Otherwise, just don't rebase `feature` and instead _merge_ `master` to `feature`.

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio I think this comment should be part of the answer. I read the answer and thought "Great, now I know why...but what's the best way to handle all these bogus commits?" I've been doing `git push -f` to avoid infinite merge conflicts next time I rebase, but I hadn't thought of the case where someone else had been working on the branch and would have a copy of the old history.

Comment: After rebase I didn't force push my feature branch but I did `git pull` and then `git push`, does it break anything? Logs seem OK. There is no duplicate commits. Or I just did a merge commit after all?

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio: To be honest, I'm totally confused by your last drawing. Isn't the purpose of rebasing to put the feature branch on top of masters HEAD (F)? But now the feature branch is still branched of at commit C?

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio But now what happens if you rebase `feature` onto `master` or merge `feature` into `master`? You'll base `feature` on `F` but have `F'` at HEAD?

Comment: @airborne Running `git pull --rebase` rebases the current branch on top of its corresponding _remote branch_, not `master`. In this case, it would be the equivalent of saying `git rebase origin/feature`.

Comment: @r.r Git is going to drop `F'` when rebasing `feature` on top of `master`, since `F` contains the same changes. The resulting history would look like this: `A-B-C-F-D-E`.

Comment: @EnricoCampidoglio FYI, in your third diagram (after _"At that point, you rebase feature on top of master, which applies D and E:"_), the diagram contains `D` and `E` -- I believe they're actually meant to be `D'` and `E'`

Comment: @Seth Since there are no other `D` and `E` commits in that diagram, I kept them _as-is_ to keep things simple. But, yes, you're correct in that those are technically _new commits_, so they should be noted as `D'` and `E'`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 41):

If the remote versions of `master` and `feature/branch` are up-to-date individually, then simply reset your local feature branch

```
git checkout feature/branch
git fetch origin feature/branch
git reset --hard origin/feature/branch
```

then if you want to bring in changes from the `master` branch,

```
git rebase origin/master
```

Comment: Might it be clearer to say "bring in changes *from* the master branch"?

Answer (score 8):

When you rebased your feature branch on top of master, you created a bunch of new commits. However, your `origin/feature` branch is still pointing to the old ones. This is the situation after the rebase:

```
C' (feature)
B'
A'
* (master, origin/master)
*
*
| C (origin/feature)
| B
| A
|/
* some base commit
```

While the commit `A'` contains a similar change set as commit `A`, it is by no means the same commit. It contains a different tree, and has a different parent.

Now, when you try to pull `feature` again, you try to create this history:

```
* (feature)
|\
C'|
B'|
A'|
* | (master, origin/master)
* |
* |
| C (origin/feature)
| B
| A
|/
* some base commit
```

You are merging two branches that have introduced very similar, jet different changes. This is bound to create a ton of conflicts, apart from being entirely pointless.

What you need to do is inform your upstream repo about the rebase by using `git push -f`. *This will loose the old history, and replace it with the rewritten one*.

The alternative is to avoid using `git rebase` on branches that you have already pushed to any other repository, or avoid `git rebase` altogether. *This is the cleaner approach*: It results in the history as it has happened, instead of telling lies about history as `git rebase` does. That's at least what I prefer.

Comment: Downvoted for 'avoid git rebase altogether'. `git rebase` is a useful tool that can be critical for effective devops, especially on large teams. Just because you don't understand how to use something properly doesn't mean you should tell other people to avoid it.

Comment: @siliconrockstar You did notice that I only proposed "avoid `git rebase` altogether" as an *alternative*? An alternative that I happen to like better, but still an alternative? I know that there are situations where you must use `git rebase`. I've worked with both rebasing and merging, and I know why I prefer doing `git merge`. Why do you think that it deserves a downvote that I advocate the better option (imho) a bit?

Comment: Because your *opinion* on what is the 'better option' is valueless. Depending on the use case, either option could be better or worse. Blanket opinions on how to solve non-specific problems get my downvote on principle.

Answer (score 4):

The `have 27 and 2 different commits each` is telling you that you now have 27 new commits from `master` and 2 new commits in your branch that are not present in `origin/<yourbranch>`.

Because `origin/<yourbranch>` has been massively changed by the rebase, it no longer has a common base with `origin/<yourbranch>`.  Therefore, you don't want to then pull the changes from `origin/<yourbranch>` after the rebase, because, as you see, all H*** breaks loose.

If you know there are changes in `origin/<yourbranch>` that you need in your local branch, then pull those before you rebase.

If you are sure no one has changed `origin/<yourbranch>` since your last push (a safe bet if this is your own feature branch), you can use `push --force` to put them into sync again.  Then `origin/<yourbranch>` will again have the same base as your local branch and that base will contain all the latest `master` changes.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying this but missing the last part `push --force` to the *branch*.

Answer (score 1):

This error came because `git fetch origin` has not been invoked after invoking `git checkout feature/branch`. To avoid this error in future, you could execute the below commands in sequence:

```
git checkout feature/branch
git fetch origin
git rebase master
```

Answer (score 0):

In searching for a solution. The following worked for me.

```
git checkout feature/branch
git rebase main
git pull --rebase
```

After the rebase (despite making sure I had all the latest locally), that status showed that I had to pull down the commits again on my feature branch. So I just made sure to `git pull --rebase` and it worked like a charm.

Comment: that `git pull --rebase` caused the rebase to start all over again, for me. I ended up aborting with `git rebase --abort` and then (as I was the only one working on the feature branch) `git push --force-with-lease`