# Git: how to fix a merge without squash

Tags: git, github

I merged to master without squashing now its showing every single commit that was made to my branch `myTestBranch`.

Is there any way i could fix it to show single commit?

Comment: Did you already push the merge result on remote ? If not it's not too late to go back on your local version of master and remake the merge with squash

Comment: Even if multiple developers work on the same remote there is no world-ending issue. All everyone has to do is a `git pull --rebase`. And please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: @RomainVALERI didnt get your question. I already merged my branch in master.

Comment: @User7354632781 What part of the question did you not get? *push*? If you've not yet pushed, or if you (rare but happens) have no remote repo at all, just go back in history, noone will have a conflicting history of the repo.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `rebase` but if the repository is used by multiple developers try to coordinate this since it will alter/change the history of the repository, for example:

```
$ git rebase -i <commit>
```

In where `<commit>` is the hash of the commit you would like to go back / revert, here you, you could use this to get a list of your last commits: `git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit`

When rebasing using the option `-i` (interactive) it will open your editor and show something like this:

```
pick 447dae2 my changes for foo bar
pick 452b764 1
pick 9aaf8b3 2
pick 15a6af0 3
pick f31a830 4
pick dd34521 5

# Rebase 5302aa0..dd34521 onto 5302aa0 (6 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop = remove commit
```

So here you could "fixup" or "squash" by prefixing the commits for example:

```
pick 447dae2 my changes for foo bar
f 452b764 1
f 9aaf8b3 2
f 15a6af0 3
f f31a830 4
f dd34521 5

# Rebase 5302aa0..dd34521 onto 5302aa0 (6 commands)
#
# Commands:
# p, pick = use commit
# r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
# e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
# s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
# f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
# x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
# d, drop = remove commit
```

Then you will have to push force:

```
$ git push -f
```

Your pears, may need to do:

```
$ git pull --rebase
```

Check this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42862404/1135424